# "A video of us playing computer games" or "of we playing"?

Tags: pronouns

I am not sure which one is correct. "A video of us playing computer games" or "of we playing computer games"?

Answer (score 2):

"Of us."

"We" and "us" are both plural, first-person pronouns, but "we" is only ever subjective. "Us" is objective.

Try taking out some of the extra description, and look at the phrase, "a video of us." The subject is the video, and it is described in part by being "of us." That makes "us" an object.

Now... You may be confused because "a video of us playing computer games" seems to make "us" the subject of another predicate, "playing computer games." That doesn't change the fact that "us" is the object of the video.

Only when you're referring to yourselves as the subject of the entire sentence do you say "we."